# Refresh a pop-up window with form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a web form that outputs the content of my database on a webpage. I've just switched to a new theme which uses pop-up windows.

The theme is here: https://html5up.net/

The problem I have is that the action I used on my form refreshes the page with the new output: t

```
<form method="post" id="searchform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

This doesn't work with the new theme, as it returns me to the homepage.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you hard code the action?

Comment: I don't see the "pop-up" windows in this theme.

Comment: If the theme uses pop-up windows, I imagine that they support submitting forms through ajax / without refreshing the page so you should probably look in their documentation for that.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by hard coding the action?

Comment: Maybe 'pop-up' is the wrong term -- if you hit one of the buttons you'll see the selected page appears as an overlay. The problem is using this php code any form action just returns to you the homepage.